# How to get the parent given a child in SQL SERVER 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, transitive-closure-table

I have a table like this

```
childid      parentid
------------------------
1       0
2       1
3       2
4       2
5       3
6       4
7       0
8       7
9       8
10      1
```

If I give a childid as 5, the parentid will be 1(output)

If I give a childid as 9, the parentid will be 7.(output)

i.e. the root parentid is 0 and the query should stop there.

How to solve such a query?

Please help.

Comment: ... there's no childid 5 or 9 in the data you provided?

Comment: I don't understand your examples, they don't match the data.

Comment: your question makes no sense. Read it again.

Comment: Maybe the titles of the columns are inverted

Comment: The column names are poor, he wants to provide a ParentID of 5 and recursively go up the chain until he finds one with a ChildID of 0, which would be ParentID = 1.

Comment: AndyMcKenna has successfully understood the bad-written question unlike us :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should rename your child_id to node, your parent_id to child_of.  Your column naming is a bit confusing

```
create table stack_overflow
(
node int, child_of int
);


insert into stack_overflow(node, child_of) values
(1,0),
(2,1),
(3,2),
(4,2),
(5,3),
(6,4),
(7,0),
(8,7),
(9,8),
(10,1);
```

**This works on any CTE-capable RDBMS**:

```
with find_parent(parent, child_of, recentness) as
(
    select node, child_of, 0 
    from stack_overflow
    where node = 9
    union all
    select i.node, i.child_of, fp.recentness + 1
    from stack_overflow i
    join find_parent fp on i.node = fp.child_of
)
select top 1 parent from find_parent 
order by recentness desc
```

Output:

```
parent
7
```

**[EDIT: more flexible and future-proof]**:

```
with find_parent(node_group, parent, child_of, recentness) as
(
    select node, node, child_of, 0
    from stack_overflow
    where node in (5,9)
    union all
    select fp.node_group, i.node, i.child_of, fp.recentness + 1
    from stack_overflow i
    join find_parent fp on i.node = fp.child_of
)
select q.node_group as to_find, parent as found 
from find_parent q 
join
(
    select node_group, max(recentness) as answer
    from find_parent
    group by node_group 
) as ans on q.node_group = ans.node_group and q.recentness = ans.answer 
order by to_find
```

Output:

```
to_find     found
5           1
9           7
```

If you're using **Postgres**, the above code could be shortened to:

```
with recursive find_parent(node_group, parent, child_of, recentness) as
(
    select node, node, child_of, 0
    from stack_overflow
    where node in (5,9)
    union all
    select fp.node_group, i.node, i.child_of, fp.recentness + 1
    from stack_overflow i
    join find_parent fp on i.node = fp.child_of
)
select distinct on (node_group) node_group as to_find, parent as found 
from find_parent 
order by to_find, recentness desc
```

DISTINCT ON rocks! :-)

Answer (score 4):

If ALL you want is the root ParentID, you can use this recursive function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION test_func
(
    @ParentID int
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @result int;
    DECLARE @childID int;

    SET @childID = (SELECT ChildID FROM YourTable WHERE ParentID = @ParentID)

    IF (@childID = 0)
        SET @result = @ParentID
    ELSE
        SET @result = dbo.test_func(@childID)

    RETURN @result    
END
GO
```

then in your main query:

```
SELECT dbo.test_func(5)
```

Passing in 5 returns 1, 9 returns 7 based on your provided data.  If you need every ParentID that is up that chain, you should probably use a CTE.

Comment: I am getting error

Msg 217, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
Maximum stored procedure, function, trigger, or view nesting level exceeded (limit 32).

Comment: Does it work for a child that isn't > 32 levels from the root?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a recursive query, you should use Common Table Expressions. I will give you a link with an example very similar that the one you're using.

I think [here](http://www.stephenforte.net/PermaLink,guid,e49d76b2-f11a-4444-9c20-b02579a22f55.aspx) is the solution. It helped me some months ago.

Answer (score 0):

A simple of example of getting the parent ID matching a given child ID is:

```
select parentid 
from MyTable 
where childid = 5
```

However, for the data above, this will return no records.