# Selecting Which month of a particular year, contributed most to sales?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I will have to produce a result set which returns the month in each year that produced the highest sales? The tables of interest would be the products table, the order table and the date-time table. The current ERD for this table structure is [image: database structure]

Here is my issue what i have tried is creating a common table expression which displays the total sales per month per year for all the years and months stored in the database, which is this

```
`WITH sales_year_and_month AS 
(SELECT 
       year, 
       month, 
       SUM(orders_table.product_quantity * dim_products.product_price_in_£) AS total_sales 
       from public.dim_date_times
       JOIN public.orders_table on public.orders_table.date_uuid = public.dim_date_times.date_uuid
      JOIN public.dim_products on public.dim_products.product_code = public.orders_table.product_code
      GROUP BY year, month
      ORDER BY total_sales DESC)`
```

Which returns something along the lines of this [image: sales_year_and_month_ouput]

now this table i want to select out the month of a particular year, which contributed most to sales?

I've tried multiple ways and still haven't been able to answer on how to do it properly, i figured it might be an issue of how i fundamentally understand these topics. Would anyone care to share how they would approach this question?

Comment: Should provide sample data and desired result as formatted text tables and/or DDL - not images. Could you just apply filter for "particular year"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select max record of each group on a group by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30157306/select-max-record-of-each-group-on-a-group-by)

Comment: @June7 It halfway does too but that is only after looking at the ranking window function which the previous people have replied to. Without knowing that, i would've struggled with that answer but thank you June, i'm just reading more about the different functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are after a list of year, month and total_sales for the highest sales for each year. Using `row_number() over()` allows for a convenient way to do this. Fow each `partition` the numbers start at 1 with the `order by DESC` determining which row is assigned 1 (the highest sales). Then later we just filter for all the row numbers equal to 1.

```
WITH sales_year_and_month
AS (
    SELECT
          *
        , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY year ORDER BY total_sales DESC) AS rn
    FROM (
        SELECT
              year
            , month
            , SUM(orders_table.product_quantity * dim_products.product_price_in_ £) AS total_sales
        FROM PUBLIC.dim_date_times
        JOIN PUBLIC.orders_table ON PUBLIC.orders_table.date_uuid = PUBLIC.dim_date_times.date_uuid
        JOIN PUBLIC.dim_products ON PUBLIC.dim_products.product_code = PUBLIC.orders_table.product_code
        GROUP BY year
            , month
        )
    )
SELECT
      year
    , month
    , total_sales
FROM sales_year_and_month
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY year
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I had no idea about row number and partition. It doesn't state it in my course and i was struggling immensly with that question. I will be looking over this properly to gain a better understanding and Thank you also for editing my question. I do kind of understand it, it potentially seperates every year by the most sales and then the subsequent query selects the RN 1 which will be the first entry for each partitioned year.

Comment: (it seperates every year) = `partition by`, then **within each partition** the `order by` determines which row is assigned 1. so by using sales DESC we assign 1 to the highest sales month and because of the partition this happens each year. i.e. row numbering restarts at 1 for each partition and order by fine tunes which row gets 1

Answer (score 1):

You can use window function like row_number() to pick the month with the highest  sale. Here is an example

```
WITH sales_year_and_month AS 
(
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY dd.year ORDER BY t.total_sales DESC) AS RN
  FROM (
         SELECT dd.year, 
                dd.month, 
                SUM(O.product_quantity * P.product_price_in_£) AS total_sales 
         from public.dim_date_times dd
         JOIN public.orders_table O
           ON O.date_uuid = dd.date_uuid
         JOIN public.dim_products P
           ON P.product_code = O.product_code
         GROUP BY dd.year, 
                  dd.month) t
)
SELECT year,
       month,
       total_sales
FROM sales_year_and_month
WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: I knew i could count on a fellow Gooner, Just to ask if i understood this corrrectly, it partitions every year and seperates them, then it orders it by highest sales order. In the subsquent query we select everything and also the first row number of the partitioned years which should be the highest sales month of that particular year

Comment: You got it right @jstevenage. With row_number() function, you are assigning a rank for each of the months of a given year based on Sales, and then finally retrieving only those records that are ranked first (rn=1).