# Postgres COUNT number of column values with INNER JOIN

Tags: database, postgresql, count, inner-join, aggregate-filter

I am creating a report in Postgres 9.3. This is my [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/6ce465/5).
Basically I have two tables, `responses` and `questions`, the structure is:

```
responses
->id
->question_id
->response

questions
->id
->question
->costperlead
```

for the column `response` there can only be 3 values, `Yes/No/Possbily`,
and my report should have the columns:

```
  question_id
, # of Yes Responses
, # of No Responses
, # of Possbily Responses
, Revenue
```

Then:

```
# of Yes Responses - count of all Yes values in the response column
# of No Responses - count of all No values in the response column
# of Possbily Responses - count of all 'Possbily' values in the response column
```

Revenue is the `costperlead`  * (Number of Yes Responses + Number of Possibly Responses).

I don't know how to construct the query, I'm new plus I came from MySQL so some things are different for postgres. In my SQL Fiddle sample most responses are Yes and Null, it's ok eventually, there will be Possibly and No.

So far I have only:

```
SELECT a.question_id
FROM responses a
INNER JOIN questions b ON a.question_id = b.id
WHERE a.created_at = '2015-07-17'
GROUP BY a.question_id;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the only predicate filters rows from table `responses`, it would be most efficient to aggregate responses first, then join to questions:

```sql
SELECT *, q.costperlead * (r.ct_yes + r.ct_maybe) AS revenue
FROM  (
   SELECT question_id
        , count(*) FILTER (WHERE response = 'Yes')      AS ct_yes
        , count(*) FILTER (WHERE response = 'No')       AS ct_no
        , count(*) FILTER (WHERE response = 'Possibly') AS ct_maybe
   FROM   responses
   WHERE  created_at = '2015-07-17'
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) r
JOIN   questions q ON q.id = r.question_id;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=5606a4733b6d28c8cab049f1b537ddba)*

This uses the aggregate `FILTER` clause (in Postgres 9.4 or later). See:

- [Aggregate columns with additional (distinct) filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136251/how-can-i-simplify-this-game-statistics-query/27141193#27141193)

Aside: consider implementing `response` as [`boolean`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-boolean.html) type with `true`/`false`/`null`.

For Postgres **9.3**:

```sql
SELECT *, q.costperlead * (r.ct_yes + r.ct_maybe) AS revenue
FROM  (
   SELECT question_id
        , count(response = 'Yes' OR NULL)      AS ct_yes
        , count(response = 'No' OR NULL)       AS ct_no
        , count(response = 'Possibly' OR NULL) AS ct_maybe
   FROM   responses
   WHERE  created_at = '2015-07-17'
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) r
JOIN   questions q ON q.id = r.question_id;
```

<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/09485f/1)</sub>

Comprehensive comparison of techniques:

- [For absolute performance, is SUM faster or COUNT?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/27572/3684)

Comment: [Err] ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
LINE 5:         , count(*) FILTER (WHERE r.response = 'Yes') AS ct_y...

Comment: @JoeneFloresca: I added a solution for pg 9.3.

Comment: Wow thank you so much for your help and explanation, it works fine but last question, your GROUP BY 1? Why is it 1? OR Do I need that?

Comment: @JoeneFloresca: In your fiddle you have no 'Possibly' values, just NULL. That contradicts the question? `GROUP BY 1` is a shorthand syntax with positional reference as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10398558/939860

Comment: Yes, you're right but if ever that the're will never be a NULL value? is it still ok to use the GROUP BY 1 without affecting the accuracy of the results?

Comment: That syntax is not related to having NULL values in the row in any way. It's just short for `GROUP BY question_id` here.

Comment: Wow thank you so much, for the help an all this information :)

Answer (score 4):

You should try:

```
SELECT a.question_id, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN a.response = 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NumsOfYes, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN a.response = 'No' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NumsOfNo,
       SUM(CASE WHEN a.response = 'Possibly' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NumOfPossibly,
       costperlead  * SUM(CASE WHEN a.response = 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + SUM(CASE WHEN a.response = 'Possibly' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS revenue
FROM responses a 
     INNER JOIN questions b ON a.question_id = b.id 
GROUP BY a.question_id, b.costperlead
```

Comment: I got an error Sir, ERROR: column b.response does not exist Position: 29

Comment: Thanks for helping Sir but seems giving me incorrect results, coz if you check the responses table question_id = 44 has 2 response for Yes, then the others are null, but the result as per your query gives 2 count for Yes, No and Possibly?

Comment: This uses the aggregate function `count()` incorrectly, which counts all values except NULL. Whether the expression yields `true` or `false` does not mater to `count()`.

Comment: Modified with the use of SUM.

Comment: Hi thank you so much it works well but @ErwinBrandstetter works for me better plus the explanations. I'll up vote this instead :) Thanks!