# crosstab in PostgreSQL, count

Tags: postgresql, join, count, crosstab

Crosstab function returns error:

> No function matches the given name and argument types

I have in table clients, dates and type of client.
Example:

```
CLIENT_ID | DATE    | CLI_TYPE
    1234  |  201601 | F
    1236  |  201602 | P
    1234  |  201602 | F
    1237  |  201601 | F
```

I would like to get number of clients(distinct) group by date and then count all clients and sort them by client type (but types: P i F put in row and count client, if they are P or F)

Something like this:

```
DATE   | COUNT_CLIENT | P | F
201601 | 2            | 0 | 2
201602 | 2            | 1 | 1
```

Comment: Please show what you tried, and also your version of Postgres. And ideally also actual table definitions - complete `CREATE TABLE` statement with data types and constraints.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT date
     , count(DISTINCT client_id) AS count_client
     , count(*) FILTER (WHERE cli_type = 'P') AS p
     , count(*) FILTER (WHERE cli_type = 'F') AS f
FROM   clients
GROUP  BY date;
```

This counts *distinct* clients per day, and *total* rows for client_types 'P' and 'F'. It's undefined how you want to count multiple types for the same client (or whether that's even possible).

About aggregate `FILTER`:

- [Postgres COUNT number of column values with INNER JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31514856/postgres-count-number-of-column-values-with-inner-join/31515503#31515503)

`crosstab()` might make it faster, but it's pretty unclear what you want exactly.
About `crosstab()`:

- [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)