# Calculate the number of single / double / tripple rooms from a rooming table

Tags: sql, postgresql, count

I have a `hotels` table and I would like to know how many single/double/triple rooms I have.

Sample data:

| room_id | user_id | user_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Bob |
| 2 | 11 | John |
| 2 | 22 | Jane |
| 3 | 111 | Jessi |
| 3 | 222 | Arthur |
| 3 | 333 | Dorra |
| 4 | 444 | Carl |
| 4 | 555 | James |
| 4 | 666 | Noel |
| 5 | 33 | Bill |
| 5 | 44 | Bell |
| 6 | 55 | Tina |
| 6 | 66 | Timor |

Examples:
`room_id` 1 has only a single occurrence. That's one "single" room.
`room_id` 2 appears twice so it's a "double" room. Same for `room_id` 5 and 6. So we have a total of 3 "double" rooms.

I need an SQL query to get the count of single/double/triple rooms. Like this:

| single | double | tripple |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 2 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First extract the number of occurrences by `room_id` and then count single, double and tripple rooms using conditional aggregation.

```sql
select 
    count(*) filter (where c = 1) single_room,
    count(*) filter (where c = 2) double_room,
    count(*) filter (where c = 3) tripple_room
from 
(
 select room_id, count(*) c from _table group by room_id
) t;
```

Answer (score 2):

A more general query to get counts for *all* room sizes:

```sql
SELECT room_size
     , count(*) AS rooms
FROM  (
   SELECT count(*) AS room_size
   FROM   hotels
   GROUP  BY room_id
   ) sub
GROUP  BY room_size
ORDER  BY room_size;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=de51c408f082aa26a0a226d544809e12)*

The result is pivoted from your desired result:

```
 room_size | rooms 
-----------+-------
         1 |     1
         2 |     3
         3 |     2
```

To pivot (and extract any room sizes from the same basic query) use `crosstab()`. See:

- [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)

```sql
SELECT single, double, tripple
FROM   crosstab(
   $$
   SELECT 'any_hotel' AS dummy
        , room_size
        , count(*)::int AS rooms
   FROM  (
      SELECT count(*) AS room_size
      FROM   hotels
      GROUP  BY room_id
      ) sub
   GROUP  BY room_size
   ORDER  BY room_size
   $$
   ) AS ct (hotel text, single int, double int, tripple int);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=de51c408f082aa26a0a226d544809e12)*

```
 single | double | tripple 
--------+--------+---------
      1 |      3 |       2
```

For a small number of room sizes, this is more verbose than multiple counts with the `FILTER` clause. But it should be faster for big tables. If performance does not matter, you might as well use the `FILTER` query provided by Stefanov.

Related:

- [Postgres COUNT number of column values with INNER JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31514856/postgres-count-number-of-column-values-with-inner-join/31515503#31515503)